# Как сделать валидацию полей input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Создаю таблицу при помощи jquery в ней есть  3 input, не могу понять как седлать валидацию для input которые идут в один ряд tr. Нужно чтоб когда 3 инпута в ряду заполнились  галочка "V" стала зеленого цвета и так работало для каждого  ряда отдельно.

```js
   $(".add-table-row").click(function() {

      let table = $("#table-interactive tbody");
      let markup = `  <tr class="row-interactive-table" >
                                <td class="counter-tr"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <label> <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ФИО" ></label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label > <input type="email" placeholder="Введите E-mail" ></label>
                                </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <label > <input type="tel" placeholder="Введите Телефон" ></label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="check-tr-row">
                                   V

                                </td>
                                <td class="close-tr-row">
                                    <div class="close-tr">
                                        X
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`;
      table.append(markup);

      //  считаем и выводим строки таблицы
      table.each(function() {
        $('.counter-tr', this).each(function(i) {
          $(this).text('' + (i + 1))
        })
      });

      // удаляем по крестику
      $(".close-tr").click(function() {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      });


    });
```

```css
.close-tr {
color: red
}
  
.check-tr-row {
  color: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="invite-input-area">

      <table class="table invite-input-table table-responsive-md" id="table-interactive">
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <a href="#" class="add-table-row"> + Добавить</a>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/ возможно этот плагин подойдет

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-form-validation-plugins/ вот еще десятка, это только по первой ссылке в гугле, на самом деле если поискать то их сотни.